# Liblog .NetStandard 2.0

Tags: .net, .net-standard-2.0, liblog

I recently used Liblog solution in my project to get logging abstraction.
Everything is working fine but i have one small question.

My project is .Net Standard 2.0, hence i defined a compiler symbol `"LIBLOG_PORTABLE"`

After adding this, i am not able to call `LogProvider.GetCurrentClassLogger();` as it is not available after above declaration.
Hence now i am accessing my logger using following way.

```
LogProvider.SetCurrentLogProvider(new Logging.LogProviders.SerilogLogProvider());
Logger = LogProvider.GetLogger("SerilogLog");
```

However, i am just confused how it supports logging abstraction for .Net Standard 2.0 if i am explicitly providing all these.
Is it a correct way of doing it or i am missing something?

Answer (score 0):

There is a [sample in the Wiki](https://github.com/damianh/LibLog/wiki/Using).

```
public class MyClass
{
    private static readonly ILog Logger = LogProvider.For<MyClass>(); 

    public MyClass()
    {
        using(LogProvider.OpenNestedContext("message"))
        using(LogProvider.OpenMappedContext("key", "value"))
        {
            Logger.Info(....);
        }
    }
}
```

For more detailed reason why it is done so, please [refer to the Wiki](https://github.com/damianh/LibLog/wiki/Using).